# Еще об интернет-сленге

Tags: сленг

Интернет-сленг тут уже не раз обсуждали, спрошу и я. А именно: мне всегда было интересно, почему "бородатую" шутку, часто выкладываемую картинку и т.д. называют "баян"? При чем тут, собственно, музыкальный инструмент или русский сказитель?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово *баян* заменило собой в интернет-сленге знакомую всем **байку** :

> Этимологический словарь Крылова
> БАЙКА
> (сказка) Общеславянское слово, образованное
> от бай – "говорун"; вспомним и глагол баить, о
> котором в словаре Даля: говорить, болтать,
> беседовать, рассказывать, разговаривать,
> толковать. В русском языке немало поговорок с
> этим глаголом. Всяк правду знает, да не всяк
> правду бает. **Щи хлебай, да поменьше бай**.
> Много знай, да мало бай.

Если нет новой темы, пользователи рано или поздно переходят на старые заезженные вопросы, приколы или анекдоты - ба(Й)яны...

Answer (score 2):

Слышала, что это от бородатого анекдота "Хоронили тёщу, порвали два баяна", который слишком часто повторялся на каком-то ресурсе.

Answer (score 1):

Мне всё-таки самым разумным объяснением кажется параллель с музыкальным инструментом. Сейчас молодёжь не особо жалует русскую народную музыку, впрочем, как и всю культуру, и считает, что это нудное старьё, заезженное и неинтересное. Баян - один из характерных символов русской культуры. Когда слышу это слово, не могу не вспомнить, как в мою музыкальную школу ходили детишки, которых родители заставляли играть на этом "немодном" инструменте, что, разумеется, радости им не доставляло. Вот как-то так и провели аналогию, частенько встречаясь с этим инструментом в жизни))

Answer (score 0):

Это много где обсуждается. Кажется, тут тоже было.
Тем не менее повторю. Убедительной версии происхождения не существует, как и вообще в отношении все сленговых образований - за единичными исключениями.

Возведение к сказителю Баяну (Бояну) как раз легко объяснить ("предание старины глубокой") - но насколько оно верно?!
Аналогично, впрочем, и с инструментом... Тоже вроде как нечто, что все давным-давно слышали - и забыть успели. Но опять же - только на словах, никаких доказательств.

Comment: Да нет, здесь, по-моему, не было.